# Understand Op Registration and Kernel Linking in TensorFlow

Tags: c++, kernel, registration, swig, tensorflow

I am fairly new to TensorFlow and right now looking into the custom op development. I have already read the official tutorial but I feel a lot of things happen behind the scenes and I do not always want to put my custom ops in **user_ops** directory.

As such, I took up an [example **word2vec**](http://ttps://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/models/embedding/word2vec.py)

which uses a custom "Skipgram" op whose registration is defined here:
**/word2vec_ops.cc**
and whose kernel implementation is here:
**/word2vec_kernels.cc**

Looking at the build file, I tried to build individual targets

1) `bazel build -c opt tensorflow/models/embedding:word2vec_ops`
This generates bunch of object files as expected.

2) `bazel build -c opt tensorflow/models/embedding:word2vec_kernels`
Same for this.

3) `bazel build -c opt tensorflow/models/embedding:word2vec_kernels:gen_word2vec`

This last build uses a custom rule namely `tf_op_gen_wrapper_py`
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/tensorflow.bzl#L197-L231

Interesting to note that this only depends on Op Registration and not on the kernel itself.

After all above, if I build `py_binary` itself using

`bazel build -c opt tensorflow/models/embedding:word2vec`

it works fine, but I fail to see where and how the kernel c++ code linked?

Additionally, I would also like to understand the `tf_op_gen_wrapper_py` rule and the whole compilation/linking procedure that goes behind the scenes for ops registration.

Thanks.

Answer (score 26):

When [adding a new kind of operation to TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/how_tos/adding_an_op/index.html), there are two main steps:

1. [Registering the "op"](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/how_tos/adding_an_op/index.html#define-the-ops-interface), which involves defining an interface for the operation, *and*
2. [Registering one or more "kernels"](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/how_tos/adding_an_op/index.html#implement-the-kernel-for-the-op), which involves defining implementation(s) for the operation, perhaps with specialized implementations for different data types, or device types (like CPU or GPU).

Both steps involve writing C++ code.
Registering an op uses the [`REGISTER_OP()` macro](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/4455f81c3dc07a77ac133dec24690968e121370a/tensorflow/core/framework/op.h#L253), and registering a kernel uses the [`REGISTER_KERNEL_BUILDER()` macro](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/e39d8feebb9666a331345cd8d960f5ade4652bba/tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.h#L965). These macros create static initializers that run when the module containing them is loaded. There are two main mechanisms for op and kernel registration:

1. Static linking into the core TensorFlow library, and static initialization.
2. Dynamic linking at runtime, using the [`tf.load_op_library()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/api_docs/python/framework.html#load_op_library) function.

In the case of `"Skipgram"`, we use option 1 (static linking). The ops are linked into the core TensorFlow library [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/4455f81c3dc07a77ac133dec24690968e121370a/tensorflow/core/BUILD#L384), and the kernels are linked in [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/4455f81c3dc07a77ac133dec24690968e121370a/tensorflow/core/BUILD#L501). (Note that this is not ideal: the `word2vec` ops were created before we had `tf.load_op_library()`, and so there was no mechanism for linking them dynamically.) Hence the ops and kernels are registered when you first load TensorFlow (in `import tensorflow as tf`). If they were created today, they would be dynamically loaded, such that they would only be registered if they were needed. (The SyntaxNet code has an [example](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/32ab5a58dd3714d0747da6993a01315dadbf0e0f/syntaxnet/syntaxnet/load_parser_ops.py) of dynamic loading.)

The [`tf_op_gen_wrapper_py()` rule](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/14ac2235699509f512b44b71160239c153ab413d/tensorflow/tensorflow.bzl#L196) in Bazel takes a list of *op*-library dependencies and generates Python wrappers for those ops. The reason that this rule depends only on the op registration is that the Python wrappers are determined entirely by the interface of the op, which is defined in the op registration. Notably, the Python interface has no idea whether there are specialized kernels for a particular type or device. The wrapper generator links the op registrations into a [simple C++ binary](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/e39d8feebb9666a331345cd8d960f5ade4652bba/tensorflow/python/framework/python_op_gen_main.cc) that generates Python code for each of the registered ops.
Note that, if you use `tf.load_op_library()`, you do not need to invoke the wrapper generator yourself, because `tf.load_op_library()` will generate the necessary code at runtime.

Comment: @mrry- Thanks a lot for the detailed response. It makes sense now. :)

Comment: I might add that I got burned trying to link the syntaxnet "custom" ops into an external binary, because the BUILD target in syntaxnet for one of the ops is missing "alwayslink = 1".  I think this is because without the "alwayslink" the relevant ".o" file is not linked in (there are no symbolic dependencies on the OpKernel itself) and this it doesn't register. When "alwayslink = 1" is present, the ".o" is linked in and statically registers the OpKernel when the binary is loaded.

Comment: Can someone update the links in 1, 2? They seem to 404.