# Where is the bazel rule generating the `gen_io_ops.py` file when building TensorFlow from sources?

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow, bazel

I'm trying to determine how the *gen_io_ops* module is generated by bazel when building TensorFlow from source.

---

In [tensorflow/python/ops/io_ops.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/io_ops.py), there is this piece of code:

```
from tensorflow.python.ops.gen_io_ops
[...]

# used in the TextLineReader initialization
rr = gen_io_ops._text_line_reader_v2(...)
```

referring to the `bazel-genfiles/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_io_ops.py` module (and generated by bazel when building TensorFlow).
The `_text_line_reader_v2` is a wrapper of the `TextLineReaderV2` defined in [tensorflow/tensorflow/core/kernels/text_line_reader_op.cc](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/text_line_reader_op.cc).

As far as I understand, the build step are the followings:

---

**1)** The kernel library for the `text_line_reader_op` is built in [tensorflow/tensorflow/core/kernels/BUILD](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/BUILD)

```
tf_kernel_library(
        name = "text_line_reader_op",
        prefix = "text_line_reader_op",
        deps = IO_DEPS,)
```

where `tf_kernel_library` basically looks for *text_line_reader_op.c* file and build it.

---

**2)** The `:text_line_reader_op` kernel library is then used as a dependency by the `io` library defined in [the same file](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/BUILD):

```
cc_library(
    name = "io",
    deps = [       
        ":text_line_reader_op", ...
    ],
)
```

I suppose the `io` library now contains the definition of the `TextLineReaderV2`kernel.

---

From what I get from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37556646/4282745), there should be a **third step** where the `io` library is used to generate the python wrappers that are in the `bazel-genfiles/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_io_ops.py` module. This file generation can be done by the `tf_op_gen_wrapper_py` rule in Basel or by the`tf.load_op_library()` method, but none of them seem involved.

**Does someone know where this third step is defined in the build process?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it.

---

There is indeed a call to `tf_op_gen_wrapper_py` but it's hidden in a call to `tf_gen_op_wrapper_private_py`:

```
def tf_gen_op_wrapper_private_py(name, out=None, deps=[],
                                 require_shape_functions=True,
                                 visibility=[]):
  if not name.endswith("_gen"):
    fail("name must end in _gen")
  [...]
  bare_op_name = name[:-4]
  tf_gen_op_wrapper_py(name=bare_op_name, ...
```

So the steps are the following.

In [tensorflow/tensorflow/python/BUILD](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/BUILD), there is this rule

```
tf_gen_op_wrapper_private_py(
    name = "io_ops_gen",
    [...]
)
```

And so, in this rule the `_gen` suffix will be removed (in `tf_gen_op_wrapper_private_py`) and a `gen_` prefix will be added in `tf_gen_op_wrapper_py` and therefore the `gen_io_ops.py` module will be generated by this rule.