# Tensorflow: Where is gen_logging_ops source code?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a question about this import from
*tensorflow/tensorflow/python/summary/summary.py line 53:*

`from tensorflow.python.ops import gen_logging_ops as _gen_logging_ops`

When I go to the directory **tensorflow/python/ops**, there is no such file called `gen_logging_ops`.

I am wondering how this worked out? BTW, I am tracking the r1.3 version.

Any suggestion is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45457061/4282745). **gen_** files are files generated at build time by bazel and if you build TensorFlow yourself, they can be found in the **bazel-genfiles/** directory.

The [`tf_op_gen_wrapper_py` bazel](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/tensorflow.bzl) rule is the rule generating the **gen_** files. As explained, in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37556646/4282745), this rule generates all the python wrapper of the ops defined in this [library](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/BUILD):

```
py_library(
    name = "logging_ops",
    srcs = ["ops/logging_ops.py"],
    srcs_version = "PY2AND3",
    deps = [
        ":framework_for_generated_wrappers",
        ":logging_ops_gen",
        ":util",
    ],
)
```

In the `logging_ops` case there is an indirection: the call to `tf_op_gen_wrapper_py` is hidden in `tf_gen_op_wrapper_private_py`:

```
 tf_gen_op_wrapper_private_py(
    name = "logging_ops_gen",
    visibility = [
        "//learning/brain/python/ops:__pkg__",
        "//tensorflow/python/kernel_tests:__pkg__",
    ],
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!