# tensorflow error: "No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'TPUReplicatedInput'" when restoring model

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory, generative-adversarial-network, tpu

(Novice question; sorry in advance.)

I have a pretrained (BigGAN) tensorflow model that another user developed to create images, and I would like to use it to generate new images. (If it helps to simplify the process, I do not need to train the model further; I just want to sample from the last checkpoint.) The model consists of the following four files:

```
model.ckpt-607250.data-00000-of-00001
model.ckpt-607250.index
model.ckpt-607250.meta
operative_config-603500.gin
```

I've been trying to use Google Colab (with TPU processing enabled) to restore the model using the following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import os

tf.compat.v1.enable_eager_execution()

model_path = "/content/drive/My Drive/biggan/"

resolver = tf.distribute.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver(tpu='grpc://' + os.environ['COLAB_TPU_ADDR'])
tf.config.experimental_connect_to_cluster(resolver)
tf.tpu.experimental.initialize_tpu_system(resolver)

tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()

model_path = "/content/drive/My Drive/biggan/"
saver = tf.compat.v1.train.import_meta_graph(model_path+'model.ckpt-607250.meta')
with tf.device('/TPU:0'):
  with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
    saver.restore(sess, model_path+'model.ckpt-607250')
```

However, this triggers the following error:

```
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1364     try:
-> 1365       return fn(*args)
   1366     except errors.OpError as e:

9 frames

InvalidArgumentError: No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'TPUReplicatedInput' used by {{node input0}} with these attrs: [is_mirrored_variable=false, index=-1, T=DT_INT32, N=128, is_packed=false]
Registered devices: [CPU, XLA_CPU]
Registered kernels:
  <no registered kernels>

     [[input0]]


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py in restore(self, sess, save_path)
   1333       # We add a more reasonable error message here to help users (b/110263146)
   1334       raise _wrap_restore_error_with_msg(
-> 1335           err, "a mismatch between the current graph and the graph")
   1336 
   1337   @staticmethod

InvalidArgumentError: Restoring from checkpoint failed. This is most likely due to a mismatch between the current graph and the graph from the checkpoint. Please ensure that you have not altered the graph expected based on the checkpoint. Original error:

No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'TPUReplicatedInput' used by node input0 (defined at <ipython-input-2-009a7264c288>:11)  with these attrs: [is_mirrored_variable=false, index=-1, T=DT_INT32, N=128, is_packed=false]
Registered devices: [CPU, XLA_CPU]
Registered kernels:
  <no registered kernels>

     [[input0]]
```

No matter what I do, I keep running into the same error with `TPUReplicatedInput`, and I'm not sure how to resolve it. I've been struggling with this for a few weeks, so any help that you can offer would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is your issue resolved now? Else, in order to replicate the issue, could you please provide the TensorFlow version, all the required supporting files. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The TPU does not support all tensorflow operations. If you train a model on a GPU, it is not guaranteed, that it also works on TPU.
A list with the TPU's supported operations is found [here](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/tensorflow-ops).

You can [register a new custom OP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37556646/17905764). You need to make use off C++ code and register a new opperation using the [REGISTER_OP()](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/4455f81c3dc07a77ac133dec24690968e121370a/tensorflow/core/framework/op.h#L253) macro and then register a kernel by using the [REGISTER_KERNEL_BUILDER()](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/e39d8feebb9666a331345cd8d960f5ade4652bba/tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.h#L965) macro.

This registration can be done either statically within the TensorFlow code, or can be done dynamically using [tf.load_op_library()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/load_op_library).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30799175)